# question about docker running out of memory

Tags: docker

I have a ML model which runs fine locally and I packaged it as a docker image.

So, initially on my Mac docker was configured to use just 2 GB of memory and I increased it to 8 but my application crashed with the message `killed`.

So I configured docker to use all of the system memory and it still has the same effect.

I am a little bit confused about this. Since now it has access to all system memory resources, should this not run out of memory if the same app is running fine on the host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not configure docker to use all of the system memory, the os kernel    needs memory to perform important system functions and the docker dameon process needs memory too.  if the kernel detects that there is not enough memory to perform important system functions, it starts killing processes with low priority to free up memory.

When you run app in the docker, the container and the host are isolated. When memory is not enough, what the host can do is to kill the container.

When you run app on the host and the memory is not enough, the os may try to swap memory to disk or do some gc (garbage collection).